# Github Action with Laravel to run Test Cases before merge or during Pull Requests fails

Tags: php, github-actions, pipeline, laravel-10

I have a setup where the root directory of my project holds a `.github` directory. Alongside this directory is `git`, for example, alongside `src` which inevitably has my **Laravel-Based Framework Application**.

```
.
├── .github // tests.yml resides within this directory under the workflows directory
├── README.md
├── docker-compose.yml
├── docs
└── src
```

The **Laravel** source code resides under `src` folder and when I create a **Github Action** to run tests they always fail. Below is a sample of what I have as a build script:

```yaml
name: Build & Test Main

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [main, develop]
    paths:
      - ".github/**"
      - "src/**"
jobs:
  build-test:
    name: Build & Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - name: Setting MySql 8
        run: |
          echo -e "Enable LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE in my.cnf\n"
          echo -e "SETTING secure-file-priv TO EMPTY STRING\n"
          echo -e "[mysqld]\nsecure-file-priv=''" | sudo tee -a /etc/mysql/my.cnf
          echo -e "SETTING local_infile TO ON\n"
          echo -e "[mysqld]\nlocal_infile='ON'" | sudo tee -a /etc/mysql/my.cnf
          echo -e "Start MYSQL service, it is off by default\n"
          sudo systemctl enable mysql.service
          sudo systemctl start mysql.service
          echo -e "Creating Laravel Database\n"
          mysql --host 127.0.0.1 -uroot -proot -e 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS laravel;'
          echo -e "Check new settings\n"
          mysql --host 127.0.0.1 -uroot -proot -e "SELECT @@global.secure_file_priv, @@global.local_infile"
      - uses: shivammathur/setup-php@15c43e89cdef867065b0213be354c2841860869e
        with:
          php-version: "8.1"
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Copy .env
        run: cp .env.example .env.ci

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: composer install -q --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-scripts --no-progress --prefer-dist

      - name: Generate key
        run: php artisan key:generate

      - name: Directory Permissions
        run: chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache

      - name: Run migrations and seeders
        run: php artisan migrate:fresh --seed --force

      - name: Execute tests (Unit and Feature tests) via PHPUnit
        run: php artisan test --parallel
```

Unfortunately, this does not work well as it always fails when it has to install composer. I have tried various approaches, even adding the `working-dir` option per step including globally, yet I could not get any positive results.

I can pretty much define all the services I need, as I have done with my `docker-compose.yml` file except the issue seems to lie with how the `composer.json` file gets to be read eventually.

In my project's entirety, the below directory structure shows just how my project is laid down.

```
.
├── README.md
├── docker-compose.yml
├── docs
│   └── images
└── src
    ├── CHANGELOG.md
    ├── README.md
    ├── app
    ├── artisan
    ├── bootstrap
    ├── composer.json
    ├── composer.lock
    ├── config
    ├── database
    ├── env.testing
    ├── node_modules
    ├── package-lock.json
    ├── package.json
    ├── phpspec.yaml
    ├── phpunit.xml
    ├── postcss.config.js
    ├── public
    ├── resources
    ├── routes
    ├── storage
    ├── tailwind.config.js
    ├── tests
    ├── vendor
    └── webpack.mix.js

14 directories, 15 files
```

Below are the images that show how my pipeline has been terrible failing as a result of composer not finding the `composer.json` file or its predecessor since they all live inside the `src` directory.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not failing when installing the composer dependencies, but on the step before, when copying the `.env.example` file to `.env.ci`. The `.env.example` file is not listed in your directory structure, where is it located? In the root of your project or in `src/`?

Comment: @rickdenhaan it actually is within the src directory and yes that is correct, it is failing on the step prior. If you have time, you can have a look at my codebase please, I'd appreciate that, here https://github.com/scruffycoderofficial/tribes-messenger.

Comment: The correct path is `src/.env.example`. You need to fix it in `cp`. That should fix your issue. See https://github.com/scruffycoderofficial/tribes-messenger/blob/master/src/.env.example. You can use `pwd` and `ls` commands to figure out the current location where you're at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a play around with it and this will get you up and running.

Since your job contains multiple steps that need to be executed from the `src` working directory, the easiest option is to set that as the default working directory for the job. This will conflict with your "Setting MySql 8" step (because at that point, `@actions/checkout` hasn't run yet so the `src` folder doesn't exist yet) so you need to override the working directory for that specific step.

This turns your `build-test` job into the following:

```yaml
jobs:
  build-test:
    name: Build & Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ./src
    steps:
      - name: Setting MySql 8
        run: |
          echo -e "Enable LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE in my.cnf\n"
          echo -e "SETTING secure-file-priv TO EMPTY STRING\n"
          echo -e "[mysqld]\nsecure-file-priv=''" | sudo tee -a /etc/mysql/my.cnf
          echo -e "SETTING local_infile TO ON\n"
          echo -e "[mysqld]\nlocal_infile='ON'" | sudo tee -a /etc/mysql/my.cnf
          echo -e "Start MYSQL service, it is off by default\n"
          sudo systemctl enable mysql.service
          sudo systemctl start mysql.service
          echo -e "Creating Laravel Database\n"
          mysql --host 127.0.0.1 -uroot -proot -e 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS laravel;'
          echo -e "Check new settings\n"
          mysql --host 127.0.0.1 -uroot -proot -e "SELECT @@global.secure_file_priv, @@global.local_infile"
        working-directory: .

      - uses: shivammathur/setup-php@15c43e89cdef867065b0213be354c2841860869e
        with:
          php-version: "8.1"

      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Copy .env
        run: cp .env.example .env

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: composer install -q --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-scripts --no-progress --prefer-dist

      - name: Generate key
        run: php artisan key:generate

      - name: Directory Permissions
        run: chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache

      - name: Run migrations and seeders
        run: php artisan migrate:fresh --seed --force

      - name: Execute tests (Unit and Feature tests) via PHPUnit
        run: php artisan test --parallel
```

This will get Github Actions past the setup, Composer, key generation and directory permissions steps.

`artisan migrate` will still fail, in part because the credentials and database name in the `.env.example` file do not match the database you're setting up for Github Actions but also because one of the seeds is failing. But I'll leave those to you to figure out, or ask about in a new question since that is no longer related to getting Github Actions to run.